# How to identify Entities, ValueObjects and Aggregates for a particular project in DDD pattern?

Tags: domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

I am developing an online job portal using DDD patterns.
There are many "objects" that i have figured out like Users, Jobs, Roles, Expertise, ExperienceRange, Country, State, City, Address, Subscriptions, etc

My question is **how do i figure out which of these is an entity or a value object or an aggregate?** Please advice me if you have ever faced the same dilemma.

I have made the following decision:

Entities - User, Job, SubscriptionPackage
ValueObjects - Role, Expertise, ExperienceRange, City, State, Country

I know that we should not think about persistence while doing DDD modelling but a doubt has surfaced that whichever **value objects i am storing in database should have an id or not?**

**if they have an id do they not violate the fundamental principal of ValueObjects and if we do not save them with ids then how to reference them in foreign key fields?**

Please help me answer these queries.

**If you can suggest which of the above mentioned objects are entities, which are value objects and which are aggregates that would be great.**

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 3):

When thinking of DDD, leave the DB mapping to a later stage. I know I'm repeating what you said, but just because it's true. A value object might have a DB id for other reasons (normalisation, reporting , etc).

First come up with your object model and then figure out how to map it. In some (rare) cases you might need to change slightly your object model if there's something that is too expensive to map properly (I cannot think of an example, but I don't want to be extremist).

So once more, forget about the DB - think about objects. For what reason does an entity have an id? I would say so then later it can be retrieved and modified, while keeping the same id. 
And if it is a VO is because the identity is implicit in the values of the object. Does it make sense for a User to have an id? What about an Address? Or a City?... It depends.

To give the example of a city value object, if you need to map that as FK to 'cities' table, then your City object will probably have an id, but the id is not exposed. It's a detail of the implementation. While the user id would be exposed. For example a city might be linked to a province/state and that to a country.

But in another application, where users can add cities and information about them, the city might be an Entity or even an Aggregate. It really depends on your requirements.

Having said that, the list of Entities and VOs you provided looks ok in a general way, but I don't know your requirements.

To answer the first question: you can read [Entities, Value Objects, Aggregates and Roots](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/05/21/entities-value-objects-aggregates-and-roots/) as there are some rules about what is a VO, Entity or Aggregate. The difficulty comes from how to apply them, and experience is the solution to that.

As a summary:

#### Entities

Many objects are not fundamentally defined by their attributes, but rather by a thread of continuity and identity.

#### Value Objects

Many objects have no conceptual identity. These objects describe characteristics of a thing.

#### Aggregates

Aggregates draw a boundary around one or more Entities. An Aggregate enforces invariants for all its Entities for any operation it supports.